# Read JSON Array into an Array in Ruby

Tags: json, ruby

I have a simple JSON file in AWS that has a very simple array in the format below

```
{ 
"student_ids": [5466,232,32145]
}
```

I am trying to reading the id's and place them in an array in ruby. I have access to the file and can access the data. I just can't figure out how to parse it into my ruby array

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should take a look at the [`JSON` module](https://devdocs.io/ruby~2.5/json)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following

```rb
require 'json'

hash = JSON.parse('{"student_ids": [1,2,3,3] }')

p hash["student_ids"]
```

Comment: What if I dont know the length of student_ids and would hash be the ruby array then

Comment: ruby array have dynamic length so you don have to know the length. but hash is not the array here, hash["student_ids"] is the array, you can save that into another variable.

Comment: Does the question ask for `[1,2,3,3]` to be displayed?

Comment: I think he wanted to get the student_ids array

Comment: Yea basically I want an array of student_ids within ruby to work with

Comment: @CarySwoveland how would i get [1,2,3,3] to get displayed?

Comment: U can use puts or p in short to print it to terminal

Comment: My point was that the question is "...to read the id's and *place them in an array*...". not to display the array. That is, you should write something like, `arr = JSON.parse('{"student_ids": [1,2,3,3] }')["student_ids"]`.

Comment: I get your point. but arr here is a hashmap. I just wanted to show how he can access the array inside

Comment: Did you notice `["student_ids"]` at my expression for `arr`? I'm just saying that the question asks to *return* an array. You *display* an array.